# Is there a not-ugly way to replace os.sep with '/'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have following problem:

```
"L:\GDrive\test\img.png".replace(os.sep, '/')
```

returning

```
"L:/GDrive\test/img.png"
```

Is there a way to replace all `\` characters without manually going over all possible special symbols like `\t`? Need to preserve `t` of course.

Comment: Your string does not contain three backslash characters, it contains only two. `\t` inside a string is interpreted as a tab character. Use `r"L:\GDrive\test\img.png"` to get the string you actually meant.

Comment: `\t` in a string literal means "tab", not "backslash t".

Comment: Personally, I'd use Pathlib here rather than using os.sep to join paths. Pathlib will allow you to create a path in an OS independent way and at the same time, won't strip out any escaped symbols (since you aren't using / or \)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use "r" before the path:

```
r"L:\GDrive\test\img.png".replace(os.sep, '/')
```

output:

```
'L:/GDrive/test/img.png'
```